# Start Gps Tracking again when the android application On-Resumes()

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, gps

I have build a system which is based upon tracking users current location dynamically as they move around places. The system works perfectly and updates current location of the users time after time into the firebase database. however when the application is minimized and resumed again to the same activity which is a map of course, it only shows the location of the user but does not update it in the fire-base database. now i know that the activity starts again from the OnResume() method, i have tried several things but every time i try to do something, it most of the time says that googleapiClient is not connected and then crashes right away. without manipulating the onResume, the app works perfectly but that does not update user position into the fire-base when the app is minimized and reopened from the onResume method. What should i do to the onResume() method that it starts sending user dynamic location into the firebase???
Below i have posted my code. Any help would be appreciated Thank You.

```
public class RequestLocationMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
    , GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
    , LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "RequestLocationMap";

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location lastLocation;
private Marker currentUserLocationMarker;
public static final int Request_User_Location_Code = 99;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_location_map);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: called");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkUserLocationPermission();
    }


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: called");

    mMap = googleMap;


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
}

public boolean checkUserLocationPermission() {

    Log.d(TAG, "checkUserLocationPermission: called");

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location_Code);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location_Code);

        }
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: here");

    switch (requestCode) {
        case Request_User_Location_Code:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (googleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Application requires location permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    Log.d(TAG, "buildGoogleApiClient: called");

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: called");

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                    try {

                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                RequestLocationMap.this, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                    break;
            }
        }
    });


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

    }


}
  @Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: called");

    lastLocation = location;

    if (currentUserLocationMarker != null) {
        currentUserLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Location");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

    currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14f));

    DatabaseReference myTracking = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MyTracking");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(myTracking);
    geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(location
            .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: called");

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1000:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK: {

                    break;
                }
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    Toast.makeText(RequestLocationMap.this, "App required location permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
    }


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onStop: called");

    super.onStop();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    DatabaseReference myTracking = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MyTracking");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(myTracking);
    geoFire.removeLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: called");

    super.onResume(); 



}
  }
```

Comment: When your activity stops you request to stop receiving location updates from FusedLocationAPI. In onResume(...) you never request to start receiving location updates again

Comment: @WadeWilson i tried that, it still throws an error saying googleApIClient is not connected yet

Comment: You just need to call connect on your googleAPIClient instance. I recommend calling "buildGoogleApiClient()" from onResume() that way you can always request for location updates when your activity resumes. Then check to see if your GoogleMap reference isn't null inside of "onLocationChanged". This may happen if the MapFragment takes longer to set up than the FusedLocationAPI.

Comment: @WadeWilson that absolutely worked . i just had to move buildGoogleApiClient() from onMapReady to Onresume and it started detecting user location. THANK YOU

Comment: No problem. I'll write up the answer for others to use in the future.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, do you mind accepting it?

Comment: @WadeWilson well i tried to accept it but stackoverflow says the follow (Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.)

Comment: Hmm, that's weird you should be able to make your own answer as accepted. Are you sure you're selecting the correct option?

Comment: @WadeWilson Yeah sorry i was mistakenly clicking for an Up Vote rather than the the accepted answer. (New guy in Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your app is that in the lifecycle method **onStop()** you request to stop receiving location updates from the FusedLocation API, but in the reciprocal method of **onResume()**. you never request for location updates. Furthermore, with the way your code is structured even if you did register for location updates inside of onResume(), you'd run into a problem with the GoogleClient API because it may not (more than likely, isn't) connected by the time **onResume()** gets executed.

I recommend that you call the method **buildGoogleApiClient()** from onResume instead of onCreate() (still perform the permissions check). This way the GoogleClient API is always connected while the activity is resumed. Remember to call "disconnect" on the GoogleClient API inside of onPause(). Inside of the location listener callback method you should perform a null check on the GoogleMap reference to prevent any NP-exceptions. GoogleMaps may be null during the first few executions of **onLocationChanged(Location)** because it may take more time to initialize the MapFragment than it does to receive the first location update from the FusedLocation API. I've seen the location API deliver a location update milliseconds after I requested updates.

Also, just good practice you should pair lifecycle methods with their reciprocals:

1. onCreate() -> onDestroy()
2. onStart() -> onStop()
3. onResume -> onPause()

Mixing and matching lifecycle callbacks can bite you down the line when you expecting a happens-before relationship, such as registering and deregistering for location updates when the app is paused and resumed.